# How to change a keyboard layout to Dvorak that assumes that the keyboard layout is QWERTY?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale

I use [Dvorak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKB_United_States_Dvorak.svg) as my primary keyboard layout. For writing in my native language(Bengali), I'd like to use the [Probhat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKB-Bengali-Probhat.svg) layout. But Probhat assumes that you are using a QWERTY layout. How do I make it understand that I'm using Dvorak so that it matches with the corresponding Dvorak keys?

Clarification: For example, when I press 'E'('D' in QWERTY), the Probhat layout understands it as a 'D'(ড). I want that it understands it as 'E'(ী).

Comment: Following the answer provided in [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu), I took a look at the Probhat layout(`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd`) and it seems that the characters are hardcoded to the keypositions in a keyboard. The keyboard itself assumes to be a QWERTY keyboard(macbook pro). So I guess one of the ways could be is to change the individual keymappings from QWERTY to dvorak.

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/710707/change-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file at location /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd contains the following as the last lines:

```
//
// XKB symbol :: Probhat Bangla/Bengali Keyboard Layout
// Ref: www.ankurbangla.org/images/probhat_layout.png
//

xkb_symbols "probhat" {
include "in(ben_probhat)"
name[Group1]= "Bangla (Probhat)";
};
```

In your case if I understand correctly, you should not edit this file but instead the file layout at location /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in

Locate the lines:

```
xkb_symbols "ben_probhat" {
name[Group1]= "Bangla (India, Probhat)";
```

Thereupon, starting the new layout remapping.

Note that you don't need to remap each keys 1 by 1 again because the unicodes for your language are already set for this layout! You only need to reorder the keys and this works for **any** languages and/or layouts whose phonetics are based on qwerty and the user rather wants to map it to standard dvorak.

In your case the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in looks like this:

```
xkb_symbols "ben_probhat" {
name[Group1]= "Bangla (India, Probhat)";
key <ESC>  { [ Escape ] };

// numbers
key <TLDE> { [ U200D, asciitilde   ] };
key <AE01> { [ U09E7, exclam       ] };
key <AE02> { [ U09E8, at           ] };
key <AE03> { [ U09E9, numbersign   ] };
key <AE04> { [ U09EA, U09F3    ] };
key <AE05> { [ U09EB, percent      ] };
key <AE06> { [ U09EC, asciicircum  ] };
key <AE07> { [ U09ED, U099E    ] };
key <AE08> { [ U09EE, U09CE    ] };
key <AE09> { [ U09EF, parenleft    ] };
key <AE10> { [ U09E6, parenright   ] };
key <AE11> { [ minus,     underscore   ] };
key <AE12> { [ equal,     plus         ] };
key <BKSP> { [ BackSpace               ] };

// tab, q to ] 
key <TAB>  { [   Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab     ] };
key <AD01> { [   U09A6,  U09A7  ] };
key <AD02> { [   U09C2,  U098A  ] };
key <AD03> { [   U09C0,  U0988  ] };
key <AD04> { [   U09B0,  U09DC  ] };
key <AD05> { [   U099F,  U09A0  ] };
key <AD06> { [   U098F,  U0990  ] };
key <AD07> { [   U09C1,  U0989  ] };
key <AD08> { [   U09BF,  U0987  ] };
key <AD09> { [   U0993,  U0994  ] };
key <AD10> { [   U09AA,  U09AB  ] };
key <AD11> { [   U09C7,  U09C8  ] };
key <AD12> { [   U09CB,  U09CC  ] };
key <RTRN> { [   Return                 ] };

// caps, a to ' 
//   key <CAPS> { [   Caps_Lock              ] };
key <AC01> { [   U09BE,  U0985  ] };
key <AC02> { [   U09B8,  U09B7  ] };
key <AC03> { [   U09A1,  U09A2  ] };
key <AC04> { [   U09A4,  U09A5  ] };
key <AC05> { [   U0997,  U0998  ] };
key <AC06> { [   U09B9,  U0983  ] };
key <AC07> { [   U099C,  U099D  ] };
key <AC08> { [   U0995,  U0996  ] };
key <AC09> { [   U09B2,  U0982  ] };
key <AC10> { [   semicolon,  colon      ] };
key <AC11> { [   apostrophe, quotedbl   ] };

// shift, z to /
//   key <LFSH> { [   Shift_L                ] };
key <AB01> { [   U09DF,  U09AF  ] };
key <AB02> { [   U09B6,  U09DD  ] };
key <AB03> { [   U099A,  U099B  ] };
key <AB04> { [   U0986,  U098B  ] };
key <AB05> { [   U09AC,  U09AD  ] };
key <AB06> { [   U09A8,  U09A3  ] };
key <AB07> { [   U09AE,  U0999  ] };
key <AB08> { [   comma,      U09C3  ] };
key <AB09> { [   U0964,  U0981  ] };
key <AB10> { [   U09CD,  question   ] };
key <BKSL> { [   U200C,  U0965  ] };
```

[This gives this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s3c1.png)

Now you just need to reorder the keys like this:

```
// numbers
key <TLDE> { [ grave,   asciitilde, voidsymbol, voidsymbol ] };
key <AE01> ==> key <AE01> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE02> ==> key <AE02> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE03> ==> key <AE03> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE04> ==> key <AE04> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE05> ==> key <AE05> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE06> ==> key <AE06> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE07> ==> key <AE07> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE08> ==> key <AE08> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE09> ==> key <AE09> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE10> ==> key <AE10> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AE11> ==> key <AC11>
key <AE12> ==> key <AD12>
key <BKSP> { [ BackSpace ] };

// key <TAB>  { [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab ] };
key <AD01> ==> key <AB02>
key <AD02> ==> key <AB08>
key <AD03> ==> key <AC03>
key <AD04> ==> key <AD09>
key <AD05> ==> key <AC08>
key <AD06> ==> key <AD05>
key <AD07> ==> key <AC04>
key <AD08> ==> key <AC05>
key <AD09> ==> key <AC02>
key <AD10> ==> key <AD04>
key <AD11> ==> key <AE11>
key <AD12> ==> key <AE12>
key <RTRN> { [ Return ] };

// key <CAPS> { [ Caps_Lock ] };
key <AC01> ==> key <AC01> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AC02> ==> key <AC10>
key <AC03> ==> key <AC06>
key <AC04> ==> key <AD06>
key <AC05> ==> key <AD07>
key <AC06> ==> key <AC07>
key <AC07> ==> key <AB03>
key <AC08> ==> key <AB04>
key <AC09> ==> key <AD10>
key <AC10> ==> key <AB01>
key <AC11> ==> key <AD01>

// key <LFSH> { [ Shift_L ] };
key <AB01> ==> key <AB10>
key <AB02> ==> key <AB05>
key <AB03> ==> key <AD08>
key <AB04> ==> key <AB09>
key <AB05> ==> key <AB06>
key <AB06> ==> key <AC09>
key <AB07> ==> key <AB07> <== NO CHANGE!
key <AB08> ==> key <AD02>
key <AB09> ==> key <AD03>
key <AB10> ==> key <AD11>
key <BKSL> { [ backslash,   bar,        voidsymbol, voidsymbol ] };
```

So that it looks like below in the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in

```
xkb_symbols "ben_probhat" {
name[Group1]= "Bangla (India, Probhat)";
key <ESC>  { [ Escape ] };

// numbers
key <TLDE> { [ U200D, asciitilde   ] };
key <AE01> { [ U09E7, exclam       ] };
key <AE02> { [ U09E8, at           ] };
key <AE03> { [ U09E9, numbersign   ] };
key <AE04> { [ U09EA, U09F3    ] };
key <AE05> { [ U09EB, percent      ] };
key <AE06> { [ U09EC, asciicircum  ] };
key <AE07> { [ U09ED, U099E    ] };
key <AE08> { [ U09EE, U09CE    ] };
key <AE09> { [ U09EF, parenleft    ] };
key <AE10> { [ U09E6, parenright   ] };
key <AC11> { [ minus,     underscore   ] };
key <AD12> { [ equal,     plus         ] };
key <BKSP> { [ BackSpace               ] };

// tab, q to ] 
key <TAB>  { [   Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab     ] };
key <AB02> { [   U09A6,  U09A7  ] };
key <AB08> { [   U09C2,  U098A  ] };
key <AC03> { [   U09C0,  U0988  ] };
key <AD09> { [   U09B0,  U09DC  ] };
key <AC08> { [   U099F,  U09A0  ] };
key <AD05> { [   U098F,  U0990  ] };
key <AC04> { [   U09C1,  U0989  ] };
key <AC05> { [   U09BF,  U0987  ] };
key <AC02> { [   U0993,  U0994  ] };
key <AD04> { [   U09AA,  U09AB  ] };
key <AE11> { [   U09C7,  U09C8  ] };
key <AE12> { [   U09CB,  U09CC  ] };
key <RTRN> { [   Return                 ] };

// caps, a to ' 
//   key <CAPS> { [   Caps_Lock              ] };
key <AC01> { [   U09BE,  U0985  ] };
key <AC10> { [   U09B8,  U09B7  ] };
key <AC06> { [   U09A1,  U09A2  ] };
key <AD06> { [   U09A4,  U09A5  ] };
key <AD07> { [   U0997,  U0998  ] };
key <AC07> { [   U09B9,  U0983  ] };
key <AB03> { [   U099C,  U099D  ] };
key <AB04> { [   U0995,  U0996  ] };
key <AD10> { [   U09B2,  U0982  ] };
key <AB01> { [   semicolon,  colon      ] };
key <AD01> { [   apostrophe, quotedbl   ] };

// shift, z to /
//   key <LFSH> { [   Shift_L                ] };
key <AB10> { [   U09DF,  U09AF  ] };
key <AB05> { [   U09B6,  U09DD  ] };
key <AD08> { [   U099A,  U099B  ] };
key <AB09> { [   U0986,  U098B  ] };
key <AB06> { [   U09AC,  U09AD  ] };
key <AC09> { [   U09A8,  U09A3  ] };
key <AB07> { [   U09AE,  U0999  ] };
key <AD02> { [   comma,      U09C3  ] };
key <AD03> { [   U0964,  U0981  ] };
key <AD11> { [   U09CD,  question   ] };
key <BKSL> { [   U200C,  U0965  ] };
```

[Ultimately giving the layout I assume you would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzZUz.png)

Note that you must make a backup of the original file layout before starting to edit and save it as root or otherwise you'll have to download and restore it back from freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig

Albeit I don't understand nothing from the alphabet, I hope this could help because I've been using the dvorak layout as well for many years and I hope that one day it can replace the qwerty layout from being always the standard :(

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. Props for adding the screenshots. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1: using a text editor**

1. Open the file `/etc/default/keyboard` as root. For example, you can run `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`
2. Change the line `XKBMODEL="pc105"` with your keyboard model (full list is [here](https://github.com/Webconverger/webc/blob/master/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst), starting from line 2).
3. Change the line `XKBLAYOUT="en"` with your layout (presummably "bd". See the full list above, starting from line 189).
4. Change the line `XKBVARIANT=""` with your variant (See the full list above, starting from line 284).
5. Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and press `Y`).
6. Restart the keyboard config with `sudo service keyboard-setup restart`

**Method 2: using `keyboard-configuration` tool.**

1. Install with `sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration` (you might have it installed already)
2. Run the configuration program, by typing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
3. Follow instructions to select the **model** of your keyboard, the **layout**, the **variant**, etc.
4. Restart the keyboard config with `sudo service keyboard-setup restart`

Source: adapted from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#How_to_switch_a_keyboard_layout_in_X11_.2F_graphical_desktop_environment).

Comment: The only good answer!  +1

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, I have no problem with changing layout.

Comment: The Probhat layout places characters that are similar to their english counterparts in QWERTY style. To draw an analogy, if I were using the Dvorak layout in English and then I switched to French layout, the French letters are placed in QWERTY style.

Comment: Strange. Surely some combination of the options must work. If the Bengali assumes QWERTY, then why not just select any QWERTY **model** as default? (even if yours is not)

Comment: It seems if there were a way to set `XKBLAYOUT=dvorak` then it would convert all the layouts that assume QWERTY layout to Dvorak ones. Unfortunately, that's not a valid value(I tried setting it anyway but it didn't work). It seems the only option that I'm left with is to change individual keys mapping to correspond to Dvorak layout.

Answer (score 3):

You have first to install the `ibus-avro` package. You’ll find a good description how to do it [here](https://github.com/maateen/avro/). You have to open a terminal, do `cd /usr/src` and follow the instructions.

Afterwards, you have to select the keyboard layout from the GUI as described.

Comment: I don't want to use Avro. I want to use a different layout(Probhat) while the letters corresponds to Dvorak instead of QWERTY.

Comment: Than, I just know `SCIM` which is for Asian languages. But it isn’t a Bengaline key board layout. There is a bug report in Ubuntu for Bengali (Jatiya/National) (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1570233 ). But I don’t know the difference between ` Jatiya` and ` Probhat`. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for you is to edit an existing dvorak layout.

there are several versions of the dvorak layout available in X11 :

- English (Dvorak)
- English (Dvorak, international with dead keys)
- English (Dvorak alternative international no dead keys) etc.

Look for them in the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us or /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb.

The idea is to choose one *you’re not using* — choose the most convenient one in the list, the closest to the Dvorak you’re already using — and to replace the english characters in that file with the bengali characters you want to assign each key to. (don’t forget to save a copy of the file you’re editing)

It should look like this

```
key <TLDE> { [dead_grave, dead_tilde,         grave,       asciitilde ] };

key <AE01> { [     1,     exclam,    exclamdown,      onesuperior ] };
key <AE02> { [     2,         at,   twosuperior, dead_doubleacute ] };
key <AE03> { [     3, numbersign, threesuperior,      dead_macron ] };
key <AE04> { [     4,     dollar,      currency,         sterling ] };
key <AE05> { [     5,    percent,      EuroSign,     dead_cedilla ] };
key <AE06> { [    6, dead_circumflex,    onequarter,      asciicircum ] };
key <AE07> { [     7,  ampersand,       onehalf,    dead_horn ] };
key <AE08> { [     8,   asterisk, threequarters,      dead_ogonek ] };
key <AE09> { [     9,  parenleft, leftsinglequotemark, dead_breve ] };
key <AE10> { [     0, parenright, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
key <AE11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  guillemotleft, leftdoublequotemark ] };
key <AE12> { [bracketright, braceright, guillemotright, rightdoublequotemark ] };

key <AD01> { [dead_acute, dead_diaeresis, apostrophe,        quotedbl ] };
key <AD02> { [     comma,       less,      ccedilla,         Ccedilla ] };
key <AD03> { [    period,    greater, dead_abovedot,       dead_caron ] };
key <AD04> { [     p,          P,    odiaeresis,       Odiaeresis ] };
key <AD05> { [     y,          Y,    udiaeresis,       Udiaeresis ] };
// key <AD06> { [      f,   F       ]   };
// key <AD07> { [      g,   G       ]   };
key <AD08> { [     c,          C,     copyright,             cent ] };
key <AD09> { [     r,          R,    registered,       registered ] };
key <AD10> { [     l,          L,        oslash,         Ooblique ] };
key <AD11> { [     slash,   question,  questiondown,        dead_hook ] };
// key <AD12> { [     equal,       plus,      multiply,         division ] };

key <AC01> { [     a,          A,        aacute,           Aacute ] };
key <AC02> { [     o,          O,        oacute,           Oacute ] };
key <AC03> { [     e,          E,        eacute,           Eacute ] };
key <AC04> { [     u,          U,        uacute,           Uacute ] };
key <AC05> { [     i,          I,        iacute,           Iacute ] };
key <AC06> { [     d,          D,           eth,              ETH ] };
// key <AC07> { [      h,   H       ]   };
key <AC08> { [     t,          T,         thorn,            THORN ] };
key <AC09> { [     n,          N,        ntilde,           Ntilde ] };
key <AC10> { [     s,          S,        ssharp,          section ] };
// key <AC11> { [     minus, underscore,           yen,    dead_belowdot ] };

key <AB01> { [ semicolon,      colon,     paragraph,           degree ] };
key <AB02> { [     q,          Q,    adiaeresis,       Adiaeresis ] };
// key <AB03> { [      j,   J       ]   };
key <AB04> { [     k,          K,            oe,               OE ] };
// key <AB05> { [      x,   X       ]   };
// key <AB06> { [      b,   B       ]   };
key <AB07> { [     m,          M,            mu,               mu ] };
key <AB08> { [     w,          W,         aring,            Aring ] };
// key <AB09> { [      v,   V       ]   };
key <AB10> { [     z,          Z,            ae,               AE ] };

key <BKSL> { [ backslash,        bar,       notsign,        brokenbar ] };

include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

To use to example you gave, on the line : `key <AC03>` replace `e` with `U2496`, which is the [corresponding UTF code](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/bengalichart.html). 
In the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd they use a coding like “0x10009EA” but I think you can use the UTF code you can find on this page.

once you’re done, you can save directly in either /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us or /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb you were editing (which works just fine, it just means you have a bengali layout inside a file of english layouts), or you can just copy the result into the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd and replace the default layout with the one you just created. just be careful, and leave all this code as it is :

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
   name[Group1]= "Bangla";
   key <ESC>  { [ Escape ] };
```

Then all you need to do is to delete all .xkm files from "/var/lib/xkb"
and you’re done, the layout you just edited is ready to be used.

When I created my own layout using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) (using the french layout bépo as a base to a russian layout that correspond to the bépo I’m used to) I couldn’t find to create a new layout, so that’s the way I used to make it happen.

To better illustrate this explanation, here is what my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr file looks look. first you have the default bépo layout, and then you have my bépo/russian layout. Notice that only the second, third and fourth rows are edited. the code `include "fr(bepo)"` takes care of that, so that the first row of this layout is the first row of the default bépo layout.

```
// Bépo : Improved ergonomic french keymap using Dvorak method.
// Built by community on 'Dvorak Fr / Bépo' :
// see http://www.clavier-dvorak.org/wiki/ to join and help.
// XOrg integration (1.0rc2 version) in 2008
// by Frédéric Boiteux <fboiteux at free dot fr>
//
// Bépo layout (1.0rc2 version) for a pc105 keyboard (french) :
// ┌─────┐
// │ S A │   S = Shift,  A = AltGr + Shift
// │ s a │   s = normal, a = AltGr
// └─────┘
//
// ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┲━━━━━━━━━┓
// │ # ¶ │ 1 „ │ 2 “ │ 3 ” │ 4 ≤ │ 5 ≥ │ 6   │ 7 ¬ │ 8 ¼ │ 9 ½ │ 0 ¾ │ ° ′ │ ` ″ ┃ ⌫ Retour┃
// │ $ – │ " — │ « < │ » > │ ( [ │ ) ] │ @ ^ │ + ± │ - − │ / ÷ │ * × │ = ≠ │ % ‰ ┃  arrière┃
// ┢━━━━━┷━┱───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┺━┳━━━━━━━┫
// ┃       ┃ B ¦ │ É ˝ │ P § │ O Œ │ È ` │ !   │ V   │ D Ð │ L   │ J Ĳ │ Z Ə │ W   ┃Entrée ┃
// ┃Tab ↹  ┃ b | │ é ˊ │ p & │ o œ │ è ` │ ˆ ¡ │ v ˇ │ d ð │ l / │ j ĳ │ z ə │ w ̆  ┃   ⏎   ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━┻┱────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┺┓      ┃
// ┃        ┃ A Æ │ U Ù │ I ˙ │ E ¤ │ ; ̛  │ C ſ │ T Þ │ S ẞ │ R ™ │ N   │ M º │ Ç , ┃      ┃
// ┃Maj ⇬   ┃ a æ │ u ù │ i ̈  │ e € │ , ’ │ c © │ t þ │ s ß │ r ® │ n ˜ │ m ¯ │ ç ¸ ┃      ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━┳┹────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┲┷━━━━━┻━━━━━━┫
// ┃       ┃ Ê   │ À   │ Y ‘ │ X ’ │ : · │ K   │ ? ̉  │ Q ̣  │ G   │ H ‡ │ F ª ┃             ┃
// ┃Shift ⇧┃ ê / │ à \ │ y { │ x } │ . … │ k ~ │ ' ¿ │ q ˚ │ g µ │ h † │ f ˛ ┃Shift ⇧      ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━┷━┳━━━┷━━━┱─┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┲━┷━━━━━╈━━━━━┻━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━┛
// ┃       ┃       ┃       ┃ Espace inséc.   Espace inséc. fin ┃       ┃       ┃       ┃
// ┃Ctrl   ┃Meta   ┃Alt    ┃ ␣ (Espace)      _               ␣ ┃AltGr ⇮┃Menu   ┃Ctrl   ┃
// ┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┹───────────────────────────────────┺━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "bepo" {

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    include "keypad(oss)"

    name[Group1]= "French (Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way)";

    // First row
    key <TLDE> { [          dollar,   numbersign,        endash,       paragraph ] }; // $ # – ¶
    key <AE01> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [        quotedbl,            1,         emdash, doublelowquotemark ] }; // " 1 — „
    key <AE02> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [   guillemotleft,            2,           less,  leftdoublequotemark ] }; // « 2 < “
    key <AE03> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [  guillemotright,            3,        greater, rightdoublequotemark ] }; // » 3 > ”
    key <AE04> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [       parenleft,            4,    bracketleft,      lessthanequal ] }; // ( 4 [ ≤
    key <AE05> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [      parenright,            5,   bracketright,   greaterthanequal ] }; // ) 5 ] ≥
    key <AE06> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [              at,            6,    asciicircum                 ] }; // @ 6 ^
    key <AE07> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [            plus,            7,      plusminus,        notsign ] }; // + 7 ± ¬
    key <AE08> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [           minus,            8,          U2212,     onequarter ] }; // - 8 − ¼
    key <AE09> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [           slash,            9,       division,        onehalf ] }; // / 9 ÷ ½
    key <AE10> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [        asterisk,            0,       multiply,  threequarters ] }; // * 0 × ¾
    key <AE11> { [           equal,       degree,       notequal,        minutes ] }; // = ° ≠ ′
    key <AE12> { [         percent,        grave,          U2030,        seconds ] }; // % ` ‰ ″

    // Second row
    key <AD01> { [               b,            B,            bar,      brokenbar ] }; // b B | ¦
    key <AD02> { [          eacute,       Eacute,     dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ] }; // é É ˊ ˝
    key <AD03> { [               p,            P,      ampersand,        section ] }; // p P & §
    key <AD04> { [               o,            O,             oe,             OE ] }; // o O œ Œ
    key <AD05> { [          egrave,       Egrave,     dead_grave,          grave ] }; // è È ` `
    key <AD06> { [ dead_circumflex,       exclam,     exclamdown                 ] }; // ^ ! ¡
    key <AD07> { [               v,            V,     dead_caron                 ] }; // v V ˇ
    key <AD08> { [               d,            D,            eth,            ETH ] }; // d D ð Ð
    key <AD09> { [               l,            L,    dead_stroke                 ] }; // l L /
    key <AD10> { [               j,            J,          U0133,          U0132 ] }; // j J ĳ Ĳ
    key <AD11> { [               z,            Z,          schwa,          SCHWA ] }; // z Z ə Ə
    key <AD12> { [               w,            W,     dead_breve                 ] }; // w W ̆

    // Third row
    key <AC01> { [               a,            A,             ae,             AE ] }; // a A æ Æ
    key <AC02> { [               u,            U,         ugrave,         Ugrave ] }; // u U ù Ù
    key <AC03> { [               i,            I, dead_diaeresis,  dead_abovedot ] }; // i I ̈ ˙
    key <AC04> { [               e,            E,       EuroSign,  dead_currency ] }; // e E € ¤
    key <AC05> { [           comma,    semicolon, rightsinglequotemark, dead_horn ] }; // , ; ’ ̛
    key <AC06> { [               c,            C,      copyright,          U017F ] }; // c C © ſ
    key <AC07> { [               t,            T,          thorn,          THORN ] }; // t T þ Þ
    key <AC08> { [               s,            S,         ssharp,          U1E9E ] }; // s S ß ẞ
    key <AC09> { [               r,            R,     registered,      trademark ] }; // r R ® ™
    key <AC10> { [               n,            N,     dead_tilde                 ] }; // n N ~
    key <AC11> { [               m,            M,    dead_macron,      masculine ] }; // m M ̄ º
    key <BKSL> { [        ccedilla,     Ccedilla,   dead_cedilla, dead_belowcomma ] }; // ç Ç ¸ ,

    // Fourth row
    key <LSGT> { [     ecircumflex,  Ecircumflex,          slash                 ] }; // ê Ê /
    key <AB01> { [          agrave,       Agrave,      backslash                 ] }; // à À \
    key <AB02> { [               y,            Y,      braceleft, leftsinglequotemark  ] }; // y Y { ‘
    key <AB03> { [               x,            X,     braceright, rightsinglequotemark ] }; // x X } ’
    key <AB04> { [          period,        colon,       ellipsis, periodcentered ] }; // . : … ·
    key <AB05> { [               k,            K,     asciitilde                 ] }; // k K ~
    key <AB06> { [      apostrophe,     question,   questiondown,      dead_hook ] }; // ' ? ¿ ̉
    key <AB07> { [               q,            Q, dead_abovering,  dead_belowdot ] }; // q Q ˚ ̣
    key <AB08> { [               g,            G,     dead_greek                 ] }; // g G µ
    key <AB09> { [               h,            H,         dagger,   doubledagger ] }; // h H † ‡
    key <AB10> { [               f,            F,    dead_ogonek,    ordfeminine ] }; // f F ̨ ª

    key <SPCE> { [           space, nobreakspace,     underscore,          U202F ] }; // ␣ (espace insécable) _ (espace insécable fin)
};

// ┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┲━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
// │ #   ¶ │ 1   „ │ 2   “ │ 3   ” │ 4   ≤ │ 5   ≥ │ 6     │ 7   ¬ │ 8   ¼ │ 9   ½ │ 0   ¾ │ °   ′ │ `   ″ ┃               ┃
// │ $   – │ "   — │ «   < │ »   > │ (   [ │ )   ] │ @   ^ │ +   ± │ -   − │ /   ÷ │ *   × │ =   ≠ │ %   ‰ ┃      <--      ┃
// ┢━━━━━━━┷━━━┱───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┴───┬───┺━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┫
// ┃    |<-    ┃ Б   ¦ │ Ы   Ѝ │ П   § │ О   І │ Ь   Ї │ !     │ В     │ Д   Ђ │ Л   Љ │ Ж   Ј │ З   Ѕ │ Ш     ┃      |    ┃
// ┃    ->|    ┃ б   | │ ы   ѝ │ п   & │ о   і │ ь   ї │ №   ¡ │ в   ˇ │ д   ђ │ л   љ │ ж   ј │ з   ѕ │ ш   ˘ ┃    <-'    ┃b é p o è ^ v d l j z w
// ┣━━━━━━━━━━━┻━┱─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┺━┓         ┃
// ┃             ┃ А   Ѣ │ У   Ў │ И   Й │ Е   Ё │ ;    ̛ │ Ц   ſ │ Т   Ћ │ С   ẞ │ Р   ™ │ Н   Њ │ М   º │ Щ   Џ ┃         ┃
// ┃    CAPS     ┃ а   ѣ │ у   ў │ и   й │ е   ё │ ,   ’ │ ц   © │ т   ћ │ с   ß │ р   ® │ н   њ │ м   ¯ │ щ   џ ┃         ┃a u i e , c t s r n m ç
// ┣━━━━━━━┳━━━━━┹─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┬─────┴─┲━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┫
// ┃   ^   ┃ Э   Є │ Я     │ Ю   ‘ │ Х   ’ │ :   · │ К   Ќ │ ?    ̉ │ Ъ    ̣ │ Г   Ѓ │ Ч   Ґ │ Ф   ª ┃           ^           ┃
// ┃   |   ┃ э   є │ я   \ │ ю   { │ х   } │ .   … │ к   ќ │ '   ¿ │ ъ   ° │ г   ѓ │ ч   ґ │ ф   ˛ ┃           |           ┃ê à y x . k ' q g h f
// ┣━━━━━━━┻━━━┳━━━┷━━━━━┳━┷━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┷━━━━━┳━┷━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━┻━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┫
// ┃           ┃         ┃         ┃           ␣                   NNBSP         ┃         ┃         ┃         ┃           ┃
// ┃   Ctrl    ┃  WinG   ┃   Alt   ┃           ⍽                     _           ┃  AltGr  ┃  WinD   ┃  WinM   ┃   Ctrl    ┃
// ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛

// based on a keyboard map from http://forum.bepo.fr/viewtopic.php?id=695

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "bepo_latin9" {

    // Restricts the fr(bepo) layout to latin9 symbols

    include "fr(bepo)"

    name[Group1]="French (Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way, Latin-9 only)";

    // Second row
    key <AD01> { [       Cyrillic_be,       Cyrillic_BE,                       bar,                   brokenbar ] }; // б Б | ¦
    key <AD02> { [       Cyrillic_yeru,     Cyrillic_YERU,                   U045D,                       U040D ] }; // ы Ы ѝ Ѝ
    key <AD03> { [       Cyrillic_pe,       Cyrillic_PE,                 ampersand,                     section ] }; // п П & §
    key <AD04> { [        Cyrillic_o,        Cyrillic_O,               Ukrainian_i,                  Ukrainian_I] }; // о О і І 
    key <AD05> { [ Cyrillic_softsign, Cyrillic_SOFTSIGN,              Ukrainian_yi,                Ukrainian_YI ] }; // ь Ь ї Ї
    key <AD06> { [        numerosign,            exclam,                exclamdown                              ] }; // № ! ¡
    key <AD07> { [       Cyrillic_ve,       Cyrillic_VE,                dead_caron                              ] }; // в В ˇ
    key <AD08> { [       Cyrillic_de,       Cyrillic_DE,               Serbian_dje,                 Serbian_DJE ] }; // д Д ђ Ђ
    key <AD09> { [       Cyrillic_el,       Cyrillic_EL,              Cyrillic_lje,                Cyrillic_LJE ] }; // л Л љ Љ
    key <AD10> { [      Cyrillic_zhe,      Cyrillic_ZHE,                Cyrillic_je,                 Cyrillic_JE] }; // ж Ж ј Ј
    key <AD11> { [       Cyrillic_ze,       Cyrillic_ZE,             Macedonia_dse,               Macedonia_DSE ] }; // з З ѕ Ѕ
    key <AD12> { [      Cyrillic_sha,      Cyrillic_SHA,                dead_breve                              ] }; // ш Ш ˘

    // Third row
    key <AC01> { [        Cyrillic_a,        Cyrillic_A,                     U0463,                        U0462] }; // а А ѣ Ѣ
    key <AC02> { [        Cyrillic_u,        Cyrillic_U,       Byelorussian_shortu,          Byelorussian_SHORTU] }; // у У ў Ў
    key <AC03> { [        Cyrillic_i,        Cyrillic_I,           Cyrillic_shorti,              Cyrillic_SHORTI] }; // и И й Й
    key <AC04> { [       Cyrillic_ie,       Cyrillic_IE,               Cyrillic_io,                  Cyrillic_IO] }; // е Е ё Ё
    key <AC06> { [      Cyrillic_tse,      Cyrillic_TSE,                 copyright,                       U017F ] }; // ц Ц © ſ
    key <AC07> { [       Cyrillic_te,       Cyrillic_TE,              Serbian_tshe,                 Serbian_TSHE] }; // т Т ћ Ћ
    key <AC08> { [       Cyrillic_es,       Cyrillic_ES,                    ssharp,                        U1E9E] }; // с С ß ẞ
    key <AC09> { [       Cyrillic_er,       Cyrillic_ER,                registered,                   trademark ] }; // р Р ® ™
    key <AC10> { [       Cyrillic_en,       Cyrillic_EN,              Cyrillic_nje,                 Cyrillic_NJE] }; // н Н њ Њ
    key <AC11> { [       Cyrillic_em,       Cyrillic_EM,               dead_macron,                   masculine ] }; // м М ¯ º
    key <BKSL> { [    Cyrillic_shcha,    Cyrillic_SHCHA,             Cyrillic_dzhe,                Cyrillic_DZHE] }; // щ Щ џ Џ

    // Fourth row
    key <LSGT> { [        Cyrillic_e,        Cyrillic_E,              Ukrainian_ie,                Ukrainian_IE ] }; // э Э є Є
    key <AB01> { [       Cyrillic_ya,       Cyrillic_YA,                 backslash                              ] }; // я Я \
    key <AB02> { [       Cyrillic_yu,       Cyrillic_YU,                 braceleft,         leftsinglequotemark ] }; // ю Ю { ‘
    key <AB03> { [       Cyrillic_ha,       Cyrillic_HA,                braceright,        rightsinglequotemark ] }; // х Х } ’
    key <AB05> { [       Cyrillic_ka,       Cyrillic_KA,             Macedonia_kje,               Macedonia_KJE ] }; // к К ќ Ќ
    key <AB07> { [ Cyrillic_hardsign, Cyrillic_HARDSIGN,            dead_abovering,               dead_belowdot ] }; // ъ Ъ °  ̣
    key <AB08> { [      Cyrillic_ghe,      Cyrillic_GHE,             Macedonia_gje,               Macedonia_GJE ] }; // г Г ѓ Ѓ
    key <AB09> { [      Cyrillic_che,      Cyrillic_CHE, Ukrainian_ghe_with_upturn,   Ukrainian_GHE_WITH_UPTURN ] }; // ч Ч ґ Ґ
    key <AB10> { [       Cyrillic_ef,       Cyrillic_EF,               dead_ogonek,                 ordfeminine ] }; // ф Ф ˛ ª
```

Answer (score 1):

Sooo I've never used this language but in your setting you can go to the keyboard click on layout settings, on the little +, then search for Bengali and I can see different kind of probhat, you can search for Dvorak inside, but after a few test you should find what you want.