# how to change specific keys on a keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, dvorak

I recently switched to dvorak and I love it. Since I use multiple languages I went for "programmer dvorak", a version of english dvorak. However, I would like to make some minor changes, such as having "á" on AltGr+a, rather than "å". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard layouts can be found in this localization

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

Detailed reading about this topic provided within this question:
[HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu)