# Using Caps-Lock to switch keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard-layout, capslock

On Mac OS X, the Thai keyboard layout has a neat feature: if you engage Caps-Lock, then the keyboard toggles to a standard US keyboard. Is it possible to do something similar with an Ubuntu keyboard?

I've studied [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/511142/426741) and used it to create a custom keyboard, but I haven't yet found any references suggesting that it is possible to define specific keys when the Caps-Lock key is toggled on.

Comment: Would it work to define a keyboard shortcut for the caps lock key that changes the keyboard layout? (This would prevent the caps lock key from functioning normally)

Comment: @NonnyMoose Would this affect all keyboard layouts, or could it be set up to intercept the caps lock key only when a Thai layout is used?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know how to intercept it all of the time, which is why I didn't answer at first.