# How to remove old iBus keyboard input menu items

Tags: keyboard, menu, ibus

[image]

[I added some input methods using IBus before](http://www.studymongolian.net/technical/how-to-create-linux-input-method-editor/mongolian-unicode-input-editor-for-linux/). After I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, though, they stopped working. (If I select them I just get normal English input.) I just want to get rid of them now, but I don't know how.

I tried going to **System Settings > Text Entry** but the `mongolianipa` and `MongolUnicode` ones that I want to get rid of are not listed.

[image]

Where is the menu generated from? Is there some settings file or database that I can edit?

#### Update

If I try re-adding the the MongolUnicode input method, it seems to work fine, even though there was a warning:

> /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py:38: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
>     from gi.repository import Gtk
>   /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py:39: PyGIWarning: IBus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('IBus', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
>     from gi.repository import IBus

The only noticeable problem is that it creates a double entry in the menu.

[image]

I am able to input text with the new input method. When I remove the input method in Text Entry Settings it disappears from the menu. However, the old one is still there in the menu.

**Note 1**

As a part of the [installation process](http://www.studymongolian.net/technical/how-to-create-linux-input-method-editor/mongolian-unicode-input-editor-for-linux/), a new database appears to be created:

```
sudo ibus-table-createdb -n /usr/share/ibus-table/tables/Mongol_Unicode.db -s /path/to/Mongol_Unicode.txt
```

I'm wondering if this database or an old one got corrupted at some point. Where can I find this database? Can it be edited?

**Note 2**

I'm not able to add a new input method using the standard way to add a custom layout (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/511142/373451) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)). When I try I only get a gray menu item (similar in appearance to the ones above that I am trying to remove) that does not input the characters in the custom layout, only the standard English input characters.

Comment: Can you re-add them? If so, do two appear or is there only one? What happens if you remove the entry you just added?

Comment: @KazWolfe, I updated my post with the results of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact the same problem, but I solved this issue....

First , in the new Ubuntu 16.04, you need to install the dconf editor, 
you can do this by entering :

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Second, once the software installed, open it and then go to `"org.gnome.desktop.input-sources"`

on the "sources" you will see something like this.

```
[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'anthy'), ('ibus', 'cantonhk'), ('ibus', 'quick-classic'), ('ibus', 'table:cantonhk')]
```

(my problem is the 2nd one, "cantonhk" and "quick-classic", like your issue occured)

Third, click on that line and delete the item your have problem....
my ones then becomes....

```
[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'anthy'), ('ibus', 'table:cantonhk')]
```

Finally, close the editor and reboot the machine....

Then you will get out of this issue.

Hope this helps...

Comment: My problem seemed to go away when I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 but that is good to know about `dconf-editor`. Since it worked for you I am marking this as accepted.