# How to get special characters on keyboard input?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I am taking a latin class, and I need to be able to type latin on my keyboard. Due to the fact that latin uses all the characters in english, it's been fine so far, but now I've run into a problem.

I need the characters <kbd>ā</kbd>, <kbd>ē</kbd>, <kbd>ī</kbd>, <kbd>ō</kbd>, and <kbd>ū</kbd> to be easily accessible via the keyboard (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to get ā, or something of the such).

How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you have the standard "US International" layout you need to select the variant with "dead keys" and type the diacritic sign before the letter, the same way users with layouts typical of the modern Latin derived languages always have done.

Comment: @MichaelBay could you explain how to do that? I am using Cinnamon, so the settings are different from default. Can you do this in the terminal?

Comment: You certainly can do it in terminal but I don't know the commands. And I don't know Cinnamon either... It should be in  the same place where you can change or add keyboard layouts.

Comment: @MichaelBay I've discovered how to get the dead keys layout, but I can't find anything that let's you configure it.

Comment: http://linuxblog.darkduck.com/2016/07/how-to-keyboard-layouts-cinnamon-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the **dead_macron** symbol. An example with the *English (US, international with dead keys)* keyboard layout:

Typing <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+3 followed by U results in the ū character.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Is there any way to make it shorter, like just RightAlt + u to get ū?

Comment: @ComputerGuy: I'm not aware of any standard way, but it would require that you create a [customized keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/q/510024).