# How to change persian keyboard layout on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my machine
The layout for the persian keyboard on my ubuntu is as shown in the following picture:

[image]
Where the standard layout for persian keyboard that I am used to work with and I am using on Windows is:

[image]

Are there any way to change the layout?

Comment: When seeing that, I take it that the Linux approach seems to be to switch between Persian and English (US) as needed rather than including it all in one layout. But indeed, you can [create a custom layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu) if you like.

Comment: I'm a Persian, and in both Ubuntu & Windows I see the Persian Layout is same. Because of which key/keys you need to change the layout?

Comment: @αғsнιη because of پ-\‍-< and lots of other keys

Comment: I see `‌‌>‌‌` and `<` are in thier place in both OS, and just `پ` is different. and the given link above is applicable for any Layouts you need to have, please follow that

Comment: I feel your pain. Everything was good in Ubuntu 16.04, but now they have ruined it. I'll let you know if I find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [repo on github](https://github.com/sinadarvi/windows-persian-keyboard-for-ubuntu) to change the keyboard layout to the windows default.