# What are the exact steps towards having cursor keys on RALT+hjkl?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, keyboard-layout

I would like the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, when pressed together with <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> to work as the left, down, up, and right arrow keys respectively.

I don't need the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to work otherwise, but it would be nice if it were perhaps an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. When used with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the cursor keys should work like the usual ones. When editing text in a Firefox edit box, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R_Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> should skip one word to the right.

How do I achieve this?

I have tried multiple things, but I wouldn't like to post them here because none of them worked. I have first tried implementing this in 2010, but there wasn't a lot of material back then. Looking around now, there doesn't seem to be much info about it either. My current OS is Ubuntu 18.04, 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new layout by opening your current keyboard layout (eg. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`) and save the file as a new file (eg. `oe`).
- Inside the first block (`xkb_symbols "basic"`) and at the end, add `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`
- In that same block, locate the key symbol for `h` (eg. `<AC06>`) and change the contents so it reads something like `key <AC06> { [ h, H, Left ] };`
- Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`
- [Go to the end of the `<layoutList>` section (search for `</layoutList>`) and add the following after the last `</layout>` tag](https://askubuntu.com/a/511142/819809):

  ```
  <layout>
   <configItem>
     <name> oe </name>
     <shortDescription> oe </shortDescription>
     <description> my new keyboard layout </description>
     <languageList>
        <iso639Id> eng </iso639Id>
     </languageList>
   </configItem>
   <variantList/>
  </layout>
  ```
- Repeat for corresponding key symbols(`Right`, `Up`, `Down`) and the other keys (`j`, `k`, `l`).
- Load your newly created layout with `setxkbmap -layout oe`

*Note* : This has been tested for `h` and works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to move cursor one word to the left.