# JIS Keyboard Layout Keyboard Characters

Tags: keyboard

I type on JIS keyboard layout on my Ubuntu computer.

Unfortunately `xev` only shows the keycode values and doesn't really help with actually changing the values.  I can't seem to figure how to assign the unused keys on my JIS keyboard.

[image]

[image]

Could someone provide a similar picture or names for the JIS keys?  There are 5 additional keys on JIS keyboard.

Comment: Which keys are unused?

Comment: @Akiva the five additional keys https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_JIS.png  on windows sharkeys it is 70,79 & 7B for the thumb modifiers.  On windows I have the thumb modifiers set to control keys.

Comment: And you have the values, <XXYY> for the 5 unused keys?

Comment: @Akiva no that is the problem.  Unless they are identical to sharpkeys values then 0070,0079 & 007B which I believe is different

Comment: Ah okay, you need the keycode values then? Hmmmmm, Interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/jp


// Symbols for Japanese 106-keys keyboards (by tsuka@kawalab.dnj.ynu.ac.jp).

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "106" {

    include "jp(common)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese";

    key <AE10> { [ 0, asciitilde    ] };
    key <AE13> { [ backslash, bar   ] };
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "common" {
    // "Common" keys for jp 106/109A layouts.

    key <HZTG> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Zenkaku_Hankaku, Kanji ]
    };

    key <AE01> { [ 1, exclam        ] };
    key <AE02> { [ 2, quotedbl      ] };
    key <AE03> { [ 3, numbersign    ] };
    key <AE04> { [ 4, dollar        ] };
    key <AE05> { [ 5, percent       ] };
    key <AE06> { [ 6, ampersand     ] };
    key <AE07> { [ 7, apostrophe    ] };
    key <AE08> { [ 8, parenleft     ] };
    key <AE09> { [ 9, parenright    ] };
    key <AE11> { [ minus, equal     ] };
    key <AE12> { [ asciicircum, asciitilde] };

    key <AD01> { [ q, Q         ] };
    key <AD02> { [ w, W         ] };
    key <AD03> { [ e, E         ] };
    key <AD04> { [ r, R         ] };
    key <AD05> { [ t, T         ] };
    key <AD06> { [ y, Y         ] };
    key <AD07> { [ u, U         ] };
    key <AD08> { [ i, I         ] };
    key <AD09> { [ o, O         ] };
    key <AD10> { [ p, P         ] };
    key <AD11> { [ at, grave        ] };
    key <AD12> { [ bracketleft, braceleft ] };

    key <CAPS> { [ Eisu_toggle, Caps_Lock ] };

    key <AC01> { [ a, A         ] };
    key <AC02> { [ s, S         ] };
    key <AC03> { [ d, D         ] };
    key <AC04> { [ f, F         ] };
    key <AC05> { [ g, G         ] };
    key <AC06> { [ h, H         ] };
    key <AC07> { [ j, J         ] };
    key <AC08> { [ k, K         ] };
    key <AC09> { [ l, L         ] };
    key <AC10> { [ semicolon, plus  ] };
    key <AC11> { [ colon, asterisk  ] };
    key <AC12> { [ bracketright, braceright ] };

    key <AB01> { [ z, Z         ] };
    key <AB02> { [ x, X         ] };
    key <AB03> { [ c, C         ] };
    key <AB04> { [ v, V         ] };
    key <AB05> { [ b, B         ] };
    key <AB06> { [ n, N         ] };
    key <AB07> { [ m, M         ] };
    key <AB08> { [ comma,  less     ] };
    key <AB09> { [ period, greater  ] };
    key <AB10> { [ slash, question  ] };
    key <AB11> { [ backslash, underscore] };
    key <LCTL> { [ Control_L        ] };

    key <NFER> { [ Muhenkan     ] };

    key <XFER> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Henkan, Mode_switch ]
    };

    key <HKTG> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Hiragana_Katakana, Romaji ]
    };

    key <EISU> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Eisu_toggle ]
    };

    key <KANA> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Hiragana_Katakana ]
    };

    key <PRSC> {
    type[Group1]= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Execute ]
    };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "henkan" {
    key <XFER> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Henkan, Mode_switch ]
    };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "OADG109A" {

    include "jp(common)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese (OADG 109A)";

    key <AE10> { [ 0        ] };
    key <AE13> { [ yen, bar ] };
};

// 86 keys with kana map
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "kana86" {

    include "srvr_ctrl(fkey2vt)"
    include "pc(editing)"
    include "keypad(numoperdecsep)"
    include "altwin(menu)"
    include "jp(kana)"
    include "jp(OADG109A)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese (Kana 86)";

    key  <ESC> {    [ Escape    ]   };
    key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock  ]   };
    key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace ]   };
    key  <TAB> {    [ Tab, ISO_Left_Tab ]   };
    key <RTRN> {    [ Return    ]   };
    key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L   ]   };
    key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R   ]   };
    key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L   ]   };
    key <LALT> {    [ Alt_L     ]   };
    key <SPCE> {    [ space     ]   };
    key <RALT> {    [ Alt_R     ]   };
    // For compatibility with other keyboards connected at the same time:
    key <RWIN> {    [ Super_R   ]   };
    key <RCTL> {    [ Control_R ]   };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "kana" {

    name[Group1]= "Japanese (Kana)";

    key <HZTG> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Zenkaku_Hankaku, Kanji ]
    };

    key <AE01> { [ kana_NU      ]   };
    key <AE02> { [ kana_FU      ]   };
    key <AE03> { [ kana_A, kana_a   ]   };
    key <AE04> { [ kana_U, kana_u   ]   };
    key <AE05> { [ kana_E, kana_e   ]   };
    key <AE06> { [ kana_O, kana_o   ]   };
    key <AE07> { [ kana_YA, kana_ya ]   };
    key <AE08> { [ kana_YU, kana_yu ]   };
    key <AE09> { [ kana_YO, kana_yo ]   };
    key <AE10> { [ kana_WA, kana_WO ]   };
    key <AE11> { [ kana_HO      ]   };
    key <AE12> { [ kana_HE      ]   };
    key <AE13> { [ prolongedsound   ]   };

    key <AD01> { [ kana_TA      ]   };
    key <AD02> { [ kana_TE      ]   };
    key <AD03> { [ kana_I, kana_i   ]   };
    key <AD04> { [ kana_SU      ]   };
    key <AD05> { [ kana_KA      ]   };
    key <AD06> { [ kana_N       ]   };
    key <AD07> { [ kana_NA      ]   };
    key <AD08> { [ kana_NI      ]   };
    key <AD09> { [ kana_RA      ]   };
    key <AD10> { [ kana_SE      ]   };
    key <AD11> { [ voicedsound      ]   };
    key <AD12> { [ semivoicedsound, kana_openingbracket ] };

    key <CAPS> { [ Eisu_toggle, Caps_Lock ] };
    key <AC01> { [ kana_CHI     ]   };
    key <AC02> { [ kana_TO      ]   };
    key <AC03> { [ kana_SHI     ]   };
    key <AC04> { [ kana_HA      ]   };
    key <AC05> { [ kana_KI      ]   };
    key <AC06> { [ kana_KU      ]   };
    key <AC07> { [ kana_MA      ]   };
    key <AC08> { [ kana_NO      ]   };
    key <AC09> { [ kana_RI      ]   };
    key <AC10> { [ kana_RE      ]   };
    key <AC11> { [ kana_KE      ]   };
    key <AC12> { [ kana_MU, kana_closingbracket ] };

    key <AB01> { [ kana_TSU, kana_tsu   ]   };
    key <AB02> { [ kana_SA      ]   };
    key <AB03> { [ kana_SO      ]   };
    key <AB04> { [ kana_HI      ]   };
    key <AB05> { [ kana_KO      ]   };
    key <AB06> { [ kana_MI      ]   };
    key <AB07> { [ kana_MO      ]   };
    key <AB08> { [ kana_NE, kana_comma ]    };
    key <AB09> { [ kana_RU, kana_fullstop ] };
    key <AB10> { [ kana_ME, kana_middledot ]    };
    key <AB11> { [ kana_RO      ]   };
    key <LCTL> { [ Control_L        ]   };

    key <NFER> { [ Muhenkan     ]   };

    key <XFER> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Henkan, Mode_switch ]
    };
    key <HKTG> {
    type[Group1]="PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Hiragana_Katakana, Romaji ]
    };

    key <PRSC> {
    type[Group1]= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Execute ]
    };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "nicola_f_bs" {
    key <BKSP> {
    type="",
    symbols[Group1]= [ bracketright, braceright ]
    };
    key <AE10> { [ 0, underscore        ] };
    key <AD11> { [ colon, asterisk      ] };
    key <AC11> { [ BackSpace, BackSpace ] };
    key <AC12> { [ Escape               ] };
    key <AB11> { [ at, grave            ] };
};

// Copied from macintosh_vndr/jp
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mac" {
    include "jp(kana)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese (Macintosh)";

    replace key <CAPS> { [ Caps_Lock ] };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "hztg_escape" {
    replace key <HZTG> { [ Escape ] };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dvorak" {
    include "jp(OADG109A)"
    name[Group1]= "Japanese (Dvorak)";

    key <AE11> { [ at, grave        ] };

    key <AD01> { [ colon, asterisk  ] };
    key <AD02> { [ comma, less      ] };
    key <AD03> { [ period, greater  ] };
    key <AD04> { [ p, P         ] };
    key <AD05> { [ y, Y         ] };
    key <AD06> { [ f, F         ] };
    key <AD07> { [ g, G         ] };
    key <AD08> { [ c, C         ] };
    key <AD09> { [ r, R         ] };
    key <AD10> { [ l, L         ] };
    key <AD11> { [ slash, question  ] };

    key <AC02> { [ o, O         ] };
    key <AC03> { [ e, E         ] };
    key <AC04> { [ u, U         ] };
    key <AC05> { [ i, I         ] };
    key <AC06> { [ d, D         ] };
    key <AC07> { [ h, H         ] };
    key <AC08> { [ t, T         ] };
    key <AC09> { [ n, N         ] };
    key <AC10> { [ s, S         ] };
    key <AC11> { [ minus, equal     ] };

    key <AB01> { [ semicolon, plus  ] };
    key <AB02> { [ q, Q         ] };
    key <AB03> { [ j, J         ] };
    key <AB04> { [ k, K         ] };
    key <AB05> { [ x, X         ] };
    key <AB06> { [ b, B         ] };
    key <AB08> { [ w, W         ] };
    key <AB09> { [ v, V         ] };
    key <AB10> { [ z, Z         ] };
};

// EXTRAS:

partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "sun_type6_suncompat" {
    include "sun_vndr/jp(sun_type6_suncompat)"
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "sun_type6" {
    include "sun_vndr/jp(sun_type6)"
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "sun_type7_suncompat" {
    include "sun_vndr/jp(sun_type7_suncompat)"
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "suncompat" {
    include "sun_vndr/jp(suncompat)"
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "sun_type7" {
    include "sun_vndr/jp(sun_type7)"
};
```

You can find the keycodes in here.