# Define custom keyboard layout in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I was able to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu) to create my custom xkb symbols in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and add them to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`.

It works, kind of.  In xterm, I can put `setxkbmap mycustomkeyboard` and then I can use my keyboard successfully in any application.

Also, in System Settings, Region & Language, Input Sources, I can add my custom keyboard to the list.

HOWEVER, even after doing this, the keyboard switching icon at the top only shows other installed keyboards, not my custom keyboard.  Furthermore, Super+Space still switches between all other installed keyboards but not my custom keyboard.

I also tried the following, but it didn't help:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
systemctl restart keyboard-setup
```

What have I missed?  Why doesn't my custom keyboard doesn't show in the keyboard switching options?

Comment: Did you reboot the system after having made the changes?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Looks like it works now after restarting the system! Thanks!

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson or krubo would you put an answer. The indicator and settings deamon needed restart to load the new setting.  Logout/login should be enough.

Comment: @user.dz: You made a similar request on another question and now this one. My general response would be: If you find it worth it, please feel free to submit own answers to questions which were actually solved via comments. I didn't do so at the time because I didn't consider the question/comment pairs to be of general interest, and I haven't changed my mind several years afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments from @GunnarHjalmarsson and @user.dz, after the steps I described, all that was missing was to restart the system or logout/login. The indicator and settings daemon needed restart or logout/login to load the new setting.