# Remapping doesn't work correctly (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I have recently installed UBuntu 18 LTS, I´m a beginner...
I have got a laptop with German keyboard but I am Italian so I basically tried to remap characters using a tutorial I have found here, this one [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu). However the resulting keyboard is not equal to the expected one by any chance. I started from the de file in usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols and modifying that I created my own version. But none of the modifications is correctly understood,. I modified all the file using sudo gedit.
I post here the modification I made and a snapshot of resulting layout.

```
 // based on a keyboard map from an 'xkb/symbols/de' file

default xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "latin(type4)"

    name[Group1]="German";

    key <AE02>  { [         2,   quotedbl,  twosuperior,    oneeighth ] };
    key <AE03>  { [         3,    section, threesuperior,    sterling ] };
    key <AE04>  { [         4,     dollar,   onequarter,     currency ] };

    key <AE11> {type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_PLUS_LOCK",  symbols[Group1]=
                  [ssharp, question, backslash, questiondown, 0x1001E9E ]};
    key <AE12>  { [**iacute**, **Iacute**, dead_cedilla,  dead_ogonek ] };

    key <AD03>  { [         e,          E,     EuroSign,     EuroSign ] };
    key <AD06>  { [         **y**,          **Y**    leftarrow,          yen ]  };
    key <AD11>  { [**ugrave**, **Ugrave**, dead_diaeresis, dead_abovering ] };
    key <AD12>  { [     **egrave**, plus,   asterisk,   asciitilde ]    };

    key <AC02>  { [         s,          S,                U017F,     U1E9E    ] };
    key <AC07>  { [         j,          J,        dead_belowdot, dead_abovedot   ] };
    key <AC10>  { [**ograve, Ograve**, dead_doubleacute, dead_belowdot ] };
    key <AC11>  { [**agrave, Agrave**, dead_circumflex, dead_caron ] };
    key <TLDE>  { [dead_circumflex, degree, U2032,    U2033 ] };

    key <BKSL>  { [numbersign, apostrophe, rightsinglequotemark,   dead_breve ] };
    key <AB01>  { [         **z,          Z,**       guillemotright,    U203A   ] };
    key <AB02>  { [         x,          X,        guillemotleft,    U2039   ] };
    key <AB04>  { [         v,          V,   doublelowquotemark, singlelowquotemark ]   };
    key <AB05>  { [         b,          B,  leftdoublequotemark, leftsinglequotemark ] };
    key <AB06>  { [         n,          N, rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ] };
    key <AB08>  { [     comma,  semicolon,       periodcentered,     multiply   ] };
    key <AB09>  { [    period,      colon,                U2026,     division   ] };
    key <AB10>  { [     minus, underscore,               endash,     emdash ] };
    key <LSGT>  { [     less,     greater,                  bar, dead_belowmacron ] };

    include "kpdl(comma)"
```

I have highlighted with ** ** the only things I have modified.
Here´s instead what I changed in the usr/share/x11/xbk/rules/evdev.xml file:

```
    <layout>
<configItem>
    <name> oe </name>
    <shortDescription> cust </shortDescription>
    <description> GermanCustom </description>
    <languageList>
        <iso639Id> ger </iso639Id>
</languageList>
```

added at the end, before closing layoutList tag.
To sump up what i tried to to do, my point was in the german qwertz keyboard at least to remap z and y to get a qwerty keyboard and wovel with grave accent in place of wovels with dieresis. HOwever when I press for example udieresis I get a [ so a completelz random character and checking the layout from the setting I get a completely wrong layout.
I really need to fix this, help please...

Comment: `xkb` is _really_ complicated. Why don't you just use an italian layout? In order to find out what is wrong with your layout, you'll have to tell us what exactly you expected and what the actual result was.

Comment: I would have showed but I cannot post pictures....

Comment: I see, but please try to at least explain it and give one or two examples, e.g. "I tried to change `y` to `z`, but now whenever I press the button labeled `y` it produces `x`". Or you can upload it to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and link to it in your question. Additionally, please [edit] your question and add the following information: a link to the tutorial you used, full file paths of all files you modified, and how you activated your newly designed keyboard layout.

Comment: I suspect that you have made multiple small mistakes. I would suggest that you instead simply edit the basic layout of the `xkb/symbols/de` file directly. That route would reduce the risk for typos.

Comment: @danzel I modified the question as you suggested.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson you are my hero. I changed the de and it worked smoothly, thank you very much.