# The keyboard layouts carpalx and carpalx-full are in the X Keyboard Configuration Database but not GNOME Settings

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to use the keyboard layout `carpalx-full`.

It is defined in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`.*

However, when I go to Settings > Language and Region > Input Sources > Add an Input Source > English (United States), `carpalx-full` is not listed.

Why is this and how can I change my keyboard layout to `carpalx-full`?

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME 3.34.2.

* The relevant parts of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` are the following.

```
// Carpalx layout created by Martin Krzywinski
// http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/carpalx/

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "carpalx" {

    name[Group1]= "English (Carpalx)";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar      ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [     6,    asciicircum ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [     7,    ampersand   ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenleft   ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright  ]   };
    key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
    key <AE12> {    [     equal,    plus        ]   };

    key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q       ]   };
    key <AD02> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
    key <AD03> {    [     m,    M       ]   };
    key <AD04> {    [     l,    L       ]   };
    key <AD05> {    [     w,    W       ]   };
    key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
    key <AD08> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [     b,    B       ]   };
    key <AD10> {    [ semicolon,    colon       ]   };
    key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft   ]   };
    key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

    key <AC01> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [     t,    T       ]   };
    key <AC04> {    [     n,    N       ]   };
    key <AC05> {    [     r,    R       ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [     e,    E       ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [     o,    O       ]   };
    key <AC10> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
    key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl    ]   };

    key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z       ]   };
    key <AB02> {    [     x,    X       ]   };
    key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
    key <AB04> {    [     v,    V       ]   };
    key <AB05> {    [     j,    J       ]   };
    key <AB06> {    [     k,    K       ]   };
    key <AB07> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
    key <AB08> {    [     comma,    less        ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater     ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question    ]   };

    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,         bar    ]   };
};
```

...

```
// Carpalx layout created by Martin Krzywinski
// Full optimization variant without fixed QWERTY-like ZXCV keys
// http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/carpalx/

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "carpalx-full" {

    include "us(carpalx)"
    name[Group1]= "English (Carpalx, full optimization)";

    key <AD06> {    [     b,    B       ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [     v,    V       ]   };

    key <AB04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
};
```

Comment: You need to add it to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` too.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu)