# Is there a way to make one alphanumeric key work as a modifier for another one?

Tags: keyboard-layout

While making a custom keyboard layout (see this: [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu/541899#comment2264776_541899)), is there a way to make one alphanumeric key work as a modifier for another one? Neither shift nor alt, but an alphanumeric key.

For example, `key {[a, A, aelig, AElig]};` ('E' works as a modifier for 'A' instead of Alt Gr) and `key {[e, E, aelig, AElig]};` ('A' works as a modifier for 'E' instead of Alt Gr). In both cases, pressing A+E (or E+A) gives æ, and pressing Shift+A+E (or Shift+E+A) gives Æ. Of course, single 'A' and 'E' must also work. Is it possible? How many pairs can I make? Will it also cause a side-effect of typing single 'A' and 'E' **on key release** instead of **on key press**?

Comment: Don't think so. One feature you may want to explore is [the compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose).

Comment: I also use an additional typographic layout XKBLAYOUT="us,ru" 
XKBVARIANT="," 
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,lv3:lwin_switch,misc:typo"; it's applied over both layouts, so maybe it's possible to make multiple layouts and assign a key for each one?