# keyboard layout "Belgian (Period)" does not exist?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm currently trying to transfer from Windows to Ubuntu, but the only problem is that I can't find my keyboard layout. In windows my keyboard layout is `English (US) - Belgian (Period)` but that doesn't seem to exist in Ubuntu (20.04). I've searched in `English`, `French` and `Dutch` keyboard settings. I've also searched through a few other issues but with no success.

Any tips or help? Thanks!

Comment: While there is no XKB layout named "Belgian (Period)", one of the available Belgian layouts might serve your needs. Have you tried them out? If none of them fits, can you please explain how the Belgian (Period) layout differs from the basic Belgian one.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the Belgian layout doesn't match all the keys on my keyboard, eg: Alt gr + 3 & 4 aren't correct and a few on the right side next to the Enter key

Comment: And the variants? I see 8 Belgian keyboard layouts in _Settings -> Region & Language_.

Comment: Yep, I've tried the other variants and they don't match.

Comment: Then you may want to create a [custom keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu).