# Mapping `del` functionality onto another key doesn't preserve single-press repeat functionality

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, delete, xmodmap

My `del` key is working just fine with single-press repeat actin (i.e. if I keep it pressed, it keeps deleting characters) *but* if I try to map it (or the `DEL` functionality` onto another key, this breaks.

The mapped-onto-key still works for a single press, but not for repeat presses.

My `~/.Xmodmap` looks just the same for both keys:

```
...
keycode 108 = Delete NoSymbol Delete NoSymbol Delete
...
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete NoSymbol Delete
```

(Where 108 == original `del` key and `119` is the key I'm mapping onto)

I've tried a bunch of other ways of doing this besides Xmodmap, basically, everything I could find online after hours of looking and nothing works.

Even worst, this worked perfectly fine until a few months ago, when an update broke the functionality.

Any help as to how to map the `del` key functionality onto another arbitrary key *while preserving the single-press repeat-action behaviour*, would be appreciated, I'm stuck.

This is on ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Have you tried mapping in xkb? https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu/541899#541899

Comment: `xev` provides an environment which shows which keys are repeated by output. Does the keycode 108 stroke not repeat in there either?  I see it is ISO_Level3_Shift from other references. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379699/why-is-altgr-remapped-from-keycode-108-to-keycode-92-lvl3-and-where]

Comment: just before assigning `keycode 108` remove Alt_R from modifiers, it depends on your layout (run `xmodmap` to see where Alt_R can be found), for us-layout it is `remove  mod1 = Alt_R`

Comment: @Andra ... tried, didn't work :/

Comment: which layout do you use? what's the output of `setxkbmap -query`?

Comment: rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ro,us
variant:    ,std,
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,mod_led:compose

Comment: for me it works also for _ro_. Why two _us_ with no variant - for experimenting?

Comment: @George, you said you tried what @Andra said and it didn't work??? before or after you already made changes??? It didn't work for me either AFTER I changed the 108 key (which is the Right Alt Key on my machine)... But when I restored it back to default `xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"`, and then FIRST made the `xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_R"` change, followed by the `xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Delete"` assignment, then the Right Alt key started to repeat deletes when held down.

Comment: @Andra your solution worked, can you make it a comment so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before assigning `keycode 108` remove `Alt_R` from modifiers, it depends on your layout (run `xmodmap` in terminal to see where `Alt_R` can be found), for us-layout it is:
`remove  mod1 = Alt_R`
If you already did the mapping (without removing `Alt_R` from modifiers), first restore the original situation (so that `Alt_R` exists).