# How to permanently set a custom keyboard layout for Linux console, login screen (GDM) and desktop session (GNOME/Wayland/XWayland)

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, login-screen, virtual-console, mutter

I'd like to have simple instructions of how to *permanently* and *consistently* set up a custom keyboard layout configuration for all of these user interfaces in a standard Ubuntu desktop installation with GNOME/Wayland (as of version 23.10):

- Linux console
- Login screen (GDM)
- Wayland session* (GNOME Shell, Mutter and XWayland)

(*) **both system-wide and user-specific**

1. Where do I put my custom keyboard layout file(s) and in which format?
2. What is the most straightforward way to change these settings?

---

Note: I know something about XKB, IM, `localectl`, the `keyboard-configuration` package, etc. However, in practice it is a big mess with scarce documentation. Even the [Debian wiki page about the topic](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard) explains a lot, but doesn't give clear instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the steps needed to create a new keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-a-new-keyboard-layout) Once created, and to apply it in console and login screen, you need to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself. Here is the easiest step-by-step solution:

**1. Make a copy of the keyboard layout/variant that you want to customize**

I wanted to customize the *Portuguese (Brazil, Dvorak)* layout. Therefore I made a copy of the **Br**azilian Portuguese XKB layout file:

```
$ cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br br-custom
```

**2. Edit the layout file as you wish**

Edit the copy of the layout file. You may follow the instructions in this question's answers to create your custom layout: [What are the steps needed to create a new keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/q/510024/448133)

**3. Install the customized layout file**

First, backup the original layout file:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/{br,br.bak}
```

Then install the file that you have just edited:

```
$ sudo cp br-curstom /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br
```

Note: in the commands above, substitute the `br` part by the name of the layout you are customizing.

**4. Verify that the modified layout is working**

Open the Settings application and go to `Keyboard` > `Input Sources`.

If the layout variant you want to use is not in the list of keyboard layouts, **search and add it**:

[image]

Then, click the three dots button at the right of the customized layout's name and select `View Keyboard Layout`:

[image]

If the layout file is OK, a graphical representation of it should show up. **If it doesn't, you may have introduced a syntax error when editing it or maybe included a layout component with the wrong name.** You'll need to fix it before continuing.

**5. Test the customized layout**

After selecting the new layout in Settings, it will be set up for your user's desktop session. Open a text editor and check that your customizations are working accordingly. If it doesn't work as expected, edit the layout file again and reinstall it until it's right for you. *Be careful to not overwrite the backed up version.*

**6. Apply the keyboard layout to the login screen and Linux console**

When you are 100% sure that the customized layout is working, you may apply it to the login screen and the Linux console (the pseudo-terminals that are accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F6</kbd>).

Run this command and select the keyboard layout/variant you've just modified:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

[image]

Finally, restart the PC and check if the customized layout was applied to the login screen as well.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the accepted answer, I have found that if you add a new variant in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br`, it does not appear in the list in GNOME settings. However, after adding it in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`, you can simply close the GNOME settings and reopen it and it will appear there. For the system tray to also show it, you need to restart though.