# Change keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my dell Latitude E5400, keyboard is 102 layout. how I can change my English keyboard layout Chart to English (102)?

[My laptop keyboard can be seen here.](http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/e6510_in01_tastatur1_01.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the Settings button in the upper-right corner of the screen
2. Select "System Settings".
3. Click "Text Entry". It may also be labeled "Language & Text" or "Keyboard Layout"
4. Click the "+" button beneath the list of installed keyboard layouts.
5. Choose the layout that you want to add to Ubuntu.
6. Click [Add] to add it to your list of layouts.
7. Note the keyboard shortcuts. The "Switch to next source" and "Switch to previous source" shortcuts allow you to quickly cycle through your enabled layouts. You can select each one and set a new shortcut if you'd like.
8. Change your layout. After enabling the keyboard shortcuts, you have two ways to change the keyboard layout:  Click the Language button in the Ubuntu menu bar and select the layout you want from the list. OR Press the shortcut you assigned to cycle through layouts.

Source: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

Comment: This to add and change languages, what I mean the chart of keyboard.  Ubuntu 15.10 does have the ability to change keyboard layout chart to English US (102)? such picture http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/e6510_in01_tastatur1_01.jpg

Comment: Look at the various English layouts available in step 5 - one of them should be what you need for the (102) you keep referring to.  Test all of them to see which of them suit you best...and if you still have trouble then, let us know?