# 16.04 text entry settings don't change keyboard layout

Tags: dpkg, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm running two keyboard layouts on my system. US and US dvorak. I noticed today, when I change between the two the toolbar icon is changing, but the actual layout doesn't.

The only way to change keyboard layouts right now is running

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Upon which all layouts change to the chosen layout. This layout is also displayed as the "Keyboard layout chart" regardless of the actually chosen keyboard layout. 
[Keyboard layout chart shows Dvorak layout, even though standard US layout has been chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoSoB.png)

Adding and removing layouts in "text entry settings" does nothing. Nor does launching ibus-setup from console.

I've been using the standard procedure as in http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu for years. Always worked. The layout-changer works superficially as usual, but no matter which layout is chosen, it always behaves like the system-standard (in this case: dvorak) layout and is also displayed as such in the Keyboard Layout Chart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710707/change-keyboard-layout)

Comment: No. I've been doing exactly that for 10+ years. Never had a problem with it.

Comment: Could be a regression bug or a messed up configuration. Could you please test whether this happens in a new or guest user account too? If yes, could you please test this in a different Ubuntu installation, e. g. inside a VM or on a live system (fully upgraded with the same package repositories)?

Comment: It also happens when logging in to a guest account, I didn't have time to test anything else yet.