# Just installed 18.04 in an HP 14s - wrong keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I get  a `"` with key marked as `@` and  `@` with the `"` key.  In Australia. How to change default layout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710707/change-keyboard-layout)

Comment: Edit your question and add output of: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `/etc/default/keyboard`, backup it and for a test change it to:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Then reboot and look if something changed.

You could also change your keyboard settings by:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
service keyboard-setup restart
```

You could find model numbers and layouts by:

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

Comment: thank you I see that would fix it. However I already solved it by re-installing 18.04 and choosing English(us) keyboard layou rather than my first guess of English(UK).  There is no documentation with the purchase of my new HP14s laptop(in Australia)  to indicate what the layout name is. The "base.lst" file does not list this model nor give a clue to what model corresponds with what layout. regards Chris Rathbone